# Simplify behavior on symbolic expression with limit

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, simplify

I want to simplify this symbolic expression, and then take the limit of it (this is not too hard on a paper) using Matlab

```
syms n x
sn = 8^n * n^2 * (sin(x))^(3*n)
simplify(sn^(1/n))
```

which results in

```
ans =

8*n^(2/n)*(sin(x)^(3*n))^(1/n)
```

This must be like `8 * n^(2/n) * (sin(x))^3`. However, if I use

```
x = sym('x', 'positive'); n = sym('n', 'positive');
sn = 8^n * n^2 * (sin(x))^(3*n)
simplify(sn^(1/n))
```

to obtain a similar answer and then take limit, I get:

```
limit(ans, n, inf)

ans =

8*limit(n^(2/n)*(sin(x)^(3*n))^(1/n), n == Inf)
```

instead of `8*sin(x)^3`.

If I simplify this on paper and then take limit, everything works:

```
limit(8*n^(2/n)*sin(x)^3, n, inf)

ans =

8*sin(x)^3
```

Is it possible to solve this using Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MuPAD doesn't simplify the expression, and thus can't take the limit, because you haven't provided the appropriate assumptions. It's not true that an expression such as `(sin(x)^n)^(1/n)` simplifies to `sin(x)` if `n` and `x` are positive. You need to fully restrict the range of `x` as it the argument of a periodic function:

```
x = sym('x','positive');
n = sym('n','real');
assumeAlso(x<=sym(pi));
sn = 8^n * n^2 * (sin(x))^(3*n);
sn2 = simplify(sn^(1/n))
limit(sn2, n, Inf)
```

which returns the answer you were expecting

```
ans =

8*sin(x)^3
```

If you have access to Mathematica, this sort of thing can be accomplished very easily:

```
Limit[(8^n n^2 Sin[x]^(3 n))^(1/n), n -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Reals, x >= 0, x <= \[Pi]}]
```